# How do we go from $d(x,x') \le d(x,y) +d(y,y') +d(y',x')$ to $d(x,x') \ge d(y,y') -d(x,y)-d(y',x')$?

Tags: geometry, inequality, metric-spaces

> How do we go from $d(x,x') \le d(x,y) +d(y,y') +d(y',x')$ to $d(x,x') \ge d(y,y') -d(x,y)-d(y',x')$?

I am not sure how to proceed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract $d(x,y)$ and $d(y',x')$ from both sides of your original inequality, and then relabel all $x,x'$ as $y,y'$ and vice versa.

Comment: That procedure gets $d(x,\,x^\prime)\ge d(y,\,y^\prime)-d(y,\,x)-d(x^\prime,\,y^\prime)$, so we also need to use $d(a,\,b)=d(b,\,a)$, which no doubt the original exercise allows us to assume.

Comment: Right! I had taken the symmetry as a given, assuming this is in the context of a metric space. I agree that warranted clarification, as that context was not explicitly stated.

Comment: @jawheele What do you mean relabel all? How can we just relabel things?

Comment: I mean replace $x$ by $y$, $x'$ by $y'$, $y$ by $x$, and $y'$ by $x'$. Assuming your first inequality is supposed to hold for all choices of $x,x',y,y'$ in whatever set you're working in, this is valid to do (you're just applying the first inequality to a different combination of points). If it makes the validity clearer, you might make the substitutions before the subtractions.

Comment: @jawheele Thanks. It did turn out to be clearer when I made the substitutions first. One could also start by considering the triangle inequality starting with $d(y,y')$.